# shell script stopped working --- need to rewrite?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

The script below worked on my Mac OS X.  I'm now using Ubuntu OS, and the script is no longer working.  I'm wondering if there's something that I need to change here?  I did change the first line from #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh, but it's still throwing up an error.... Essentially, I get an error when I try to run it:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

#!/bin/sh
REMOTE='ftp.example.com'
USER='USERNAME'
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
CMDFILE='/jtmp/rc.ftp'
FTPLOG='/jtmp/ftplog'
PATTERN='SampFile*'

date > $FTPLOG
rm $CMDFILE 2>/dev/null

LISTING=$(ftp -in $REMOTE <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd download
ls $PATTERN
quit
EOF )

echo "open $REMOTE" >> $CMDFILE
echo "user $USER $PASSWORD" >> $CMDFILE
echo "verbose" >> $CMDFILE
echo "bin" >> $CMDFILE
echo "cd download" >> $CMDFILE
 for FILE in $LISTING
  do
   echo "get $FILE" >> $CMDFILE
  done
echo "quit" >> $CMDFILE

  ftp -in < $CMDFILE >> $FTPLOG 2>&1

rm $CMDFILE
```

**EDIT**

I turned set -v and set -x on and it looks like it's not running the LISTING...  Any idea why?

```
REMOTE='ftp.example.com'
+ REMOTE=ftp.example.com
USER='USERNAME'
+ USER=USERNAME
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
+ PASSWORD=PASSWORD
CMDFILE='/jtmp/rc.ftp'
+ CMDFILE=/jtmp/rc.ftp
FTPLOG='/jtmp/ftplog'
+ FTPLOG=/jtmp/ftplog
PATTERN='SampFile*'
+ PATTERN=SampFile*

date > $FTPLOG
+ date
rm $CMDFILE 2>/dev/null
+ rm /jtmp/rc.ftp

LISTING=$(ftp -in $REMOTE <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd download
ls $PATTERN
quit
EOF )

echo "open $REMOTE" >> $CMDFILE
echo "user $USER $PASSWORD" >> $CMDFILE
echo "verbose" >> $CMDFILE
echo "bin" >> $CMDFILE
echo "cd download" >> $CMDFILE
 for FILE in $LISTING
  do
   echo "get $FILE" >> $CMDFILE
  done
echo "quit" >> $CMDFILE

  ftp -in < $CMDFILE >> $FTPLOG 2>&1

rm $CMDFILE./inFullRefresh.sh: 34: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `<<EOF` makes it look for `EOF` on a line by itself, and `EOF )` doesnt count.  Try changing

```
EOF )
```

to

```
EOF
)
```

Comment: yes...  figured that out just before you posted this... Thanks though :)